# Java scanner hasNextLine returns null after an object is constructed only once(?)

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

first post.

I have a list file with user information I'm trying to create objects out of, to then put into an array list. When it has read the first 4 lines it constructs the object once, and when it loops to continue reading the file it stops because hasNextResult = null. ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSuKw.png))

List file:

```
Lilly
Lilly Anderson
193.164.85.111
avatar.img
Johnny
Jonathan Anderson
224.12.8.94
avatar.img
```

Constructor:

```
public Friend(String nickname, String fullname, String lastip, String image){
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.fullname =fullname;
    this.lastip =lastip;
    this.image =image; 
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return nickname + ", " + fullname + ", " + lastip + ", " + image;
}
```

Scanner:

```
public static Friend build(InputStream in){   
    Friend friend;
            
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend = new Friend(reader.nextLine(), null, null, null);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setFullname(reader.nextLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setIp(reader.nextLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setImg(reader.nextLine());
    }
    return friend;
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Friend> al = new ArrayList<>();
            
    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream("Friends.list");
    Friend f;
    
    while((f = Friend.build(reader))!= null){
        al.add(f);
    }
    Collections.sort(al);
    printCollection(al.iterator());
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Lilly, Lilly Anderson, 193.164.85.111, avatar.img
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

It tries to read the next line after the last line, Try this: Change the code for the scanner to this:

Scanner:

```java
public static Friend build(InputStream in, int counter){   
    Friend friend;
            
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend = new Friend(reader.nextLine(), null, null, null);
    }else if(counter < 0){
    if(true){
        friend.setFullname(reader.readLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setIp(reader.nextLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setImg(reader.nextLine());
    }
        return friend;
    } else {
    return null;
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setFullname(reader.nextLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setIp(reader.nextLine());
    }
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        friend.setImg(reader.nextLine());
    }
    return friend;
  }
```

Main:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Friend> al = new ArrayList<>();
            
    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream("Friends.list");
    Friend f;
    int counter = 0;
    while((f = Friend.build(reader, counter))!= null){
        al.add(f);
        counter++;
    }
    Collections.sort(al);
    printCollection(al.iterator());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this but I get the same results sadly.

Comment: oh, Well try to buffer the answers to variables unless you want it to reply to changes in the file.

Comment: I have changed it, try now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new `Scanner` for each `friend`, try this:

```
    public static Friend build(Scanner reader){   
        Friend friend;
        
        if(reader.hasNextLine()){
            friend = new Friend(reader.nextLine(), null, null, null);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
        if(reader.hasNextLine()){
            friend.setFullname(reader.nextLine());
        }
        if(reader.hasNextLine()){
            friend.setIp(reader.nextLine());
        }
        if(reader.hasNextLine()){
            friend.setImg(reader.nextLine());
        }
        return friend;
    }
```

and call it like in:

```
...
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Friends.list");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Friend f;
 
while((f = Friend.build(reader))!= null){
     al.add(f);
}
...
```

Reason: `Scanner` kind of does read ahead the next token(s), so it is/they are already consumed when the next `Scanner` is created. From its source code:

> ```
>  // Internal buffer used to hold input
>  private CharBuffer buf;
>  
>  // Size of internal character buffer
>  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // change to 1024;
> ```

<sub>I would use a `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner` (for reading just lines)</sub>

Comment: Ahhh thank you, that solved my issue! I knew it was something silly.
I'll have to use delimiters later on I think, so I guess scanners are kinda useful for that, we'll see.